# How can I fix 'warning Expected 'this' to be used by class method ' eslint error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am creating a PDF like this inside a react Component.

export class Test extends React.PureComponent {

```
savePDF() {
  const source = document.getElementById('printContainer');
  /* eslint new-cap: ["error", { "newIsCap": false }]*/
  let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'pt', 'letter');


  let margins = { top: 50,
    left: 60,
    width: 612
  };

  pdf.fromHTML(
    source, 
    margins.left, 
    margins.top, 
    {
      width: margins.width
    },
    () => {
      pdf.save('worksheet.pdf');
    }
  );
}
```

and I am getting `warning  Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'savePDF'  class-me`

this is being called an click like this `onClick={this.savePDF}` see below

```
  render() {
       <Link
      name="save-to-pdf"
      onClick={this.savePDF}
      button="secondary">
        Save to PDF</Link>
       <div id="printContainer" className="cf-app-segment--alt cf-hearings-worksheet">...
```

Comment: Can you show the component code calling savePDF()?

Comment: The issue is, why is `savePDF` a method in the first place? It is complaining because you never use `this`, so it can just be a module-level function. There is no reason for it to be a method.

That said, using `getElementById` in a React application is a huge thing that sticks out. Maybe you want to be using `refs`, which would mean you use `this` which would avoid this error: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @loganfsmyth - can you add a note /reference link to for those who might not know the difference between "module-level function" and "method" in this context?  (seems to me like your comment and that distinction might be the answer here perhaps?)

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to hear from the user first. The answer depends on if `printContainer` is an element created by this React component, or if it's something outside React's control.

Comment: I have update the answer by showing how savePDF is being called.

Comment: @ZenaMesfin Where is `printContainer` created? That's the other important piece.

Comment: right now its an test div. I don't think!

Comment: So that means it isn't created by React? Like you don't have `<Link ...>Save to PDF></Link><div id="printContainer"></div>`. Any reason not to?

Comment: updated my answer to show its the same component

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two different answers to this question, depending on how you want to handle it.

First, the *reason* you get this error is because of the ESLint rule https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this. Specifically, this is because if something is a class method, e.g. if you are calling `this.foo()` to call a function, the whole reason to make it a method is because there are properties on `this` that you need to use.

While in many languages with `class`, most functions are methods, that is not the case in JS. If you have a class like

```
class Example {
  constructor(){
    this.data = 42;
  }
  someMethod() {
    this.someHelper(this.data);
  }

  someHelper(value){
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

the `someHelper` function would trigger the same error you are getting, because it never uses `this`, so you can just as easily do

```
class Example {
  constructor(){
    this.data = 42;
  }
  someMethod() {
    someHelper(this.data);
  }
}

function someHelper(value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

In your case, you *can* do this. Your whole `savePDF` function could be moved outside of the `class` object.

That said, it is important to ask yourself *why* something like this isn't using `this`. In most cases, you'd expect any function that works with HTML to *absolutely* use `this`, because how else, in React, is it supposed to access the element's that React has created.

So the *real* answer to your question would be to drop the

```
const source = document.getElementById('printContainer');
```

line. If you need access to the HTML element being created by React, you should be [using React's APIs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to do so. That would be done with something like

```
class SavePDFButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.printContainer = null;

    this.savePDF = this.savePDF.bind(this);
    this.handlePrintContainerRef = this.handlePrintContainerRef.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link
          name="save-to-pdf"
          onClick={this.savePDF}
          button="secondary"
        >
          Save to PDF
        </Link>
        <div 
          id="printContainer" 
          className="cf-app-segment--alt cf-hearings-worksheet" 

          ref={this.handlePrintContainerRef}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handlePrintContainerRef(el) {
    // When React renders the div, the "ref={this.handlePrintContainerRef}" will
    // make it call this function, which will store a reference.
    this.printContainer = el;
  }

  savePDF() {
    // OLD: const source = document.getElementById('printContainer');
    const source = this.printContainer;

    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that's caused by the [`class-methods-use-this`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this) ESLint rule.

It's just letting you know that your function doesn't use `this`, so you can probably make it a static function.

Comment: How can i create a static function? I do not know what that is!

Comment: The ESLint rule page that I linked has an example: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this. You can learn more about static methods in JavaScript here: https://javascript.info/class

Answer (score 3):

turn it into static function

```
static savePDF() { ... }
```

Its happening because this function isnt using `this` meaning it dosnt need to be dynamic