# Where to put a method without "this"?

Tags: javascript, oop, eslint

My code:

```
class DoIt {
  city () {
    // others operations...
    const number = 5; // from operations
    const amount = this.getAmount (number);
    // others operations...
  }
  street () {
    // others operations...
    const number = 10; // from operations
    const amount = this.getAmount (number);
    // others operations...
  }
  getAmount (number) {
    return number * 10 * 3.14 / 3; // example...
  }
}
```

I use "eslint" to check my code and I have error:

> error  Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'getAmount' 
>   class-methods-use-this

So where to put a method without "this"? This code is important for my class, so I shouldn't create helper class...

Maybe this method is not important? In OOP in other languages can exists method without 'this' in class methods?

Comment: What do you mean by `this.number(number)`? You have no function `number()` in your class?

Comment: Sorry, it was mistake. I updated my question.

Comment: Docs for the error explains it pretty well: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this

Comment: If it doesn't use `this`, then the method doesn't reference the object it is associated with … so why is it a method of that object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix 'warning Expected 'this' to be used by class method ' eslint error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163734/how-can-i-fix-warning-expected-this-to-be-used-by-class-method-eslint-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class-methods-use-this is an eslint check to see if your class method does not refer to this.  In some cases, it may be better to make it static by adding the static keyword in front of the method declaration.  In other cases, you can just ignore this check.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this